# Decoding data using charset x-IBM300 gives different results for unmappable code points on different JVMs

Tags: java, character-encoding

I'm trying to convert some data from code page IBM-300 to Unicode using a java.nio.charset.Charset object. 
As far as i can tell IBM-300 has a fixed length of 2 bytes for all of it's characters so i would expect that for every 2 bytes of input I would get 1 Unicode character. However for invalid code points I sometimes get one U+FFFD character in the output, while for others I get two such characters in the output. 
Here is an example:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;

public class CP300test{
     public static void main(String []args){
        Charset cs = Charset.forName("x-IBM300");
        byte[] cp1 = {(byte)0x41, (byte)0xB0};
        byte[] cp2 = {(byte)0x42, (byte)0x70};
        CharBuffer cb1 = cs.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(cp1));
        CharBuffer cb2 = cs.decode(ByteBuffer.wrap(cp2));
        System.out.println(cb1.length()); 
        System.out.println(cb2.length());
     }
}
```

The above code will print "1 2" on Hotspot and OpenJ9 JVMs, but on the IBM JVM running on the same Linux machine it will print "1 1". Am I missing something? Is there anything i can tweak to consistently get one U+FFFD character for every double byte un-mappable code point like the IBM JVM output? I hope to avoid having to write my own custom Charset.

Comment: FYI, apparently this is a PDF document dated 2002 documenting a specification for IBM code page 300, IBM’s representation of Kanji (Japan): ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/globalization/gcoc/attachments/CP00300.pdf